# Can iTunes open in another folder on startup?

Tags: windows, itunes

When opening iTunes, I always start at the *Music* folder, but I would like to startup in *iTunes DJ*, so I can hit play right away.

I want to have my workflow as follows:

- Hit the *startup default media player* button on my keyboard
- Hit *play* on my keyboard

But now I have to do this:

- Hit the *startup default media player* button on my keyboard
- Open back up the mini player that started
- Go to *iTunes DJ*
- Hit *play*
- Press *CTRL + M*

It would be very helpful to reduce 5 steps into just 2 again. Somehow it worked in earlier versions, but this doesn't seem to work anymore. It doesn't remember where I left off.

I'm using iTunes 10.2.1.1 with Windows-7 x64.